NET MAUI: Updating properties and enabling commands that depend on observable object fields
As we know, RelayCommand and getter-only properties need to be notified when their dependencies change. That is usually done with NotifyCanExecuteChangedForAttribute and NotifyPropertyChangedForAttribute.
But what needs to be done in cases when we access nested object fields, and not primitive types? I know that those classes also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. But that is not enough here, because that event isn't propagated to cause reevaluation of CanExecute method.
Here is an example:
There is an object of Bill.Item class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged (I have tried to use both ObservableObjectand Fody.PropertyChange, but there is no difference).
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(SaveCommand))]
[NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(NotEnoughDrinks))]
private Bill.Item billItem;

Its properties are updated through UI with XAML two-way bindings:
<Entry Placeholder="Title" Text="{Binding BillItem.Title}" />
...
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Entry Placeholder="Quantity" Text="{Binding BillItem.Quantity}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <Stepper Value="{Binding BillItem.Quantity}" Minimum="1" Increment="1" />
</HorizontalStackLayout>

SaveCommand and NotEnoughDrinks property depend on fields inside BillItem.
public bool NotEnoughDrinks => ChosenDrink?.Quantity < BillItem.Quantity;

[RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(IsSaveable))]
private void Save() {
    OnClose?.Invoke(BillItem);
}

private bool IsSaveable() {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BillItem.Title)) return false;

    return true;
}

I have found a workaround, by subscribing to PropertyChanged event and manually invoking OnPropertyChanged and NotifyCanExecuteChanged. Unfortunately that solution produces COMException and TargetInvocationException from time to time, and I am unable to find the root cause, or any message related to those exceptions. And except from that issue, I assume that this solution is not idiomatic enough because it makes code more complex.
partial void OnBillItemChanged(Bill.Item? oldValue, Bill.Item newValue) 
{
    void OnBillItemPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(NotEnoughDrinks));
            SaveCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        } 
        catch (Exception) {}
    }

    if (oldValue is not null)
        oldValue.PropertyChanged -= OnBillItemPropertyChanged;
    if (newValue is not null)
        newValue.PropertyChanged += OnBillItemPropertyChanged;
}

Is there anything that I am missing, for example an attribute, that is useful for these cases when I need to handle updates of nested ObservableObject fields? Or I really need to stick to workarounds like the one shown above?

It is very simple with ReactiveUI look at this gist

Can you remove the custom events that you made, and show the code that was using notify annotation that did not work? Maybe it can be fixed?

@H.A.H. I have updated the question to include definitions of the command and property

I still do not see the piece of code, where you re-assign the BillItem property to something else.

Billitem as reference isn't re-assigned at all, but its properties are binded through XAML to Entry field. Meaning that "deep" properties are updated through UI and two-way bindings.
UPDATE: I added that XAML code to the question.

Do you remove the PropertyChanged-EventHandler at any time? Maybe you collect a lot of EventHandlers over the time and that will cause this issue

I don't touch event handlers at all except the part that is shown in the question

Well, then you should take care to unregister those EventHandlers

Well, I do, I unsubscribe on old object, and subscribe on new object. But this is not the cause of the issue. The main issue is that I can't find straightforward way to propagate property changed events from nested model objects up to commands and dependent properties in viewmodels.

When you create an instance and assign the BillItem the PropertyChanged is registered - and that will happen whenever you create a new instance and assign the BillItem. At the end you can have a single Bill.Item with a lot of registered PropertyChanged EventHandlers and that can cause the issue. Yes, it is a guess because you do not show us the Bill.Item class and how you use both (do you reuse Bill.Item instances, do you reuse this unamed class instance - we do not know)

You can avoid that endless registration when you use the built in toolkit messenger, because it is per default a WeakReferenceMessenger
